# The "obvious" symmetry group $C_3 \times S_4$ related to the hexacode

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am studying the large Mathieu groups and more specifically the hexacode from Robert Wilson's book "The Finite Simple Groups". The following paragraph is from page 184:[The hexacode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qSmJ.jpg)

My question is related to what is underlined: How should I interpret this? What does the group "$C_3 \times S_4$ generated by scalar multiplications and those three coordinate permutations" look like?

I figured that the "$C_3$-part" of the group is there because of the (cyclic) multiplicative group {$1, \omega, \overline{\omega}$} of the field $\mathbb{F}_4$, but how come $<(1,2)(3,4); (1,3,5)(2,4,6); (1,3)(2,4)> \cong S_4$? I tried constructing $<(1,2)(3,4); (1,3,5)(2,4,6); (1,3)(2,4)>$ element by element and became only 16 different elements to be in this group. Can anyone help me to get some more insight in how this group looks like and perhaps how this is important in relation to the hexacode and the large Mathieu groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $a:=(12)(34)$, $b:=(135)(246)$, and $c:=(13)(24)$. Let $G=\langle a,b,c\rangle$. Note that $a^c=a$ while $(a^b)^c=a^{b^2}$. It follows that $N:=\{1,a,a^b,a^{b^2}\}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ of order $4$. (Isomorphic to a Klein group.) Moreover, $b^c=b^{-1}$ so $H:=\langle b,c\rangle$ is isomorphic to $S_3$.  Moreover, $H\cap N=1$, so $G=N\rtimes H$ and $G$ has order $24$.

Comment: Thank you for this great, concise answer! Nevertheless I still have some questions:

- This may be a weird question, but: how did you find this so "fast"? Have you encountered this before or is there a specific strategy you use to solve a problem like this?

- How does it follow from $b^c = b^{c^{-1}}$ that $H \cong S_3$? How can you conclude this so easily and why do you use the fact that c is an involution as argument?

- It's clear now that G has order 24, but how can I know for sure that it is isomorphic to $S_4$?

Comment: I'll try to explain a bit about the train of thought. First, it helps to know the "target", that is, that we're trying to prove that the group is $S_4$. If you hadn't told me, I'd have found it using a computer. Once that is known, I use the fact that $S_4$ has a normal subgroup isomorphic to the Klein group, so I start looking for that subgroup. Essentially, you are looking for involutions that commute with their conjugates and it doesn't take long to figure out that $a$ is one such.

Comment: Note that there was a typo in the next part, I meant $b^c=b^{-1}$. (I've fixed it.) So $H$ is generated by two elements, one of which is an involution which inverts the other. This means that $H$ is a dihedral group, in this case $D_3\cong S_3$.

As for being sure that $G$ is really $S_4$, well it is well known that $S_4\cong AGL(2,2)$ which is essentially what we have above, with a Klein group being acted on faithfully by $H\cong S_3\cong GL(2,2)$. 

If you don't like this, you could show that $H$ is core-free in $G$. As it has index $4$, this would show that $H$ is a subgroup of $S_4$.

Comment: In general, when studying an "unknown" group like this, finding some normal subgroups is very often useful as it allows to split the problem in pieces, in some sense.